# Mailchimp v3.0 API, using Perl Curl

Tags: perl, curl, mailchimp

I'm trying to find a way to do a Curl request to MailChimps new **API v3.0**, that will subscribe a user to a given list. Here is what I have thus far:

```
use warnings;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;
use JSON;

my $apikey = 'xxxx';
my $listid = 'xxxx';
my $email = 'andy@test.co.uk';
my $endpoint = "https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists";

my $json = JSON::encode_json([
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'pending',
    'merge_fields'  => [
        'FNAME'     => "andy",
        'LNAME'     => "newby"
    ]
]);

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

my $url = "$endpoint/$listid/members/" . Digest::MD5::md5(lc($email));

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apikey);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

# Starts the actual request
my $retcode = $curl->perform;

# Looking at the results...
if ($retcode == 0) {
        print("Transfer went ok\n");
        my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        print "Received response: $response_body\n";
} else {
        # Error code, type of error, error message
        print "An error happened: $retcode ".$curl->strerror($retcode)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n";
}
```

The documentation is pretty scarce, due to it being a new API. Has anyone had any success with the MailChimp v3 API, for subscribing someone in Perl? (I'm also open to suggestions for command line `curl` requests... but everything I tried with regards to that, failed with "internal server errors" coming back from MailChimp, which wasn't very helpful)

**UPDATE:** As suggested below, I enabled `verbose`, and it now spits out:

> - Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
> - Trying 184.86.100.251...
> - Connected to us6.api.mailchimp.com (184.86.100.251) port 443 (#0)
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: none   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: C=US; ST=GA; L=Atlanta; O=ROCKET SCIENCE GROUP; OU=Rocket Science Group; CN=*.api.mailchimp.com
> - start date: 2015-09-22 14:39:14 GMT
> - expire date: 2016-09-22 14:39:13 GMT
> - subjectAltName: us6.api.mailchimp.com matched
> - issuer: C=NL; L=Amsterdam; O=Verizon Enterprise Solutions; OU=Cybertrust; CN=Verizon Akamai SureServer CA G14-SHA2
> - SSL certificate verify ok.
> - Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
>
>   > PUT /3.0/lists HTTP/1.1 Authorization: Basic xxxx Host: us6.api.mailchimp.com Accept: */* Content-Type: application/json
>   >     Content-Length: 108
> - upload completely sent off: 108 out of 108 bytes < HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
> - Server nginx is not blacklisted < Server: nginx < Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8 < Content-Length: 253 <
>     X-Request-Id: 5f6ab08f-69e7-4c9b-b22a-91714331d5b7 < Link:
>     https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/ProblemDetailDocument.json;
>     rel="describedBy" < Allow: GET, POST < Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2015 11:24:32
>     GMT < Connection: close < Set-Cookie: _AVESTA_ENVIRONMENT=prod; path=/
>     <
> - Closing connection 0 Transfer went ok Received response: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Server: nginx Content-Type:
>     application/problem+json; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 253
>     X-Request-Id: 5f6ab08f-69e7-4c9b-b22a-91714331d5b7 Link:
>     https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/ProblemDetailDocument.json;
>     rel="describedBy" Allow: GET, POST Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2015 11:24:32 GMT
>     Connection: close Set-Cookie: _AVESTA_ENVIRONMENT=prod; path=/
>
> {"type":"http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/error-docs/405-method-not-allowed","title":"Method
>   Not Allowed","status":405,"detail":"The requested method and resource
>   are not compatible. See the Allow header for this resource's available
>   methods.","instance":""}

I'm not really sure what to make of that though :/

**Working code:** Thanks to TooMuchPete, I managed to get it going. For anyone who may come across this while trying to use the MailChimp API (3.0) in Perl, below is a working sample (you just need to replace the values of the email, name, api key, and list id);

```
    use WWW::Curl::Easy;
    use JSON;
    use Digest::MD5;

    my $apikey = 'xxxx-us6';
    my $listid = 'xxxx';
    my $email = 'andy@testr.co.uk';
    my $endpoint = "https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists";

    my $json = JSON::encode_json({
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'pending',
        'merge_fields'  => {
            'FNAME'     => "andy",
            'LNAME'     => "newby"
        }
    });

    my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

    my $url = "$endpoint/$listid/members/" . Digest::MD5::md5(lc($email));

    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apikey);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

    # A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
    my $response_body;
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

    # Starts the actual request
    my $retcode = $curl->perform;

    # Looking at the results...
    if ($retcode == 0) {
            print("Transfer went ok\n");
            my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            # judge result and next action based on $response_code
            print "Received response: $response_body\n";
    } else {
            # Error code, type of error, error message
            print "An error happened: $retcode ".$curl->strerror($retcode)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n";
    }
```

I hope this saves someone the grief I had :)

Comment: Try running `$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` to get the verbose output. It may help you to debug further.

Comment: @SabujHassan - thanks, I've updated my question above, to include the debug on that (auth key was taken out)

Comment: @AndrewNewby I just stopped by to say thank you and I love you. This saved me days worth of work manually creating a solution.

Comment: @ljamison no worries - I'm glad my pain saved someone else some =) hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to connect to `$endpoint` instead of `$url`.

```
my $url = "$endpoint/$listid/members/" . Digest::MD5::md5(lc($email));

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
```

should be:

```
my $url = "$endpoint/$listid/members/" . Digest::MD5::md5(lc($email));

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Comment: thanks! That was it. I've now got another error coming up, but will dig into that: `,"errors":[{"field":"","message":"Schema describes object, array found instead"}]`.

Comment: Ah... got it .... was using [] instead of {} in the JSON variable ... seems good now (get an error about the user existing, which is fine, as it does)

Comment: That's odd -- `PUT` shouldn't return an error for an existing user, that's the whole point of it, to allow add-or-update functionality. You might want to check with their API support team on that one.

Comment: yeah, the error was the fact I was using [ ] instead of a hashref: { } ... so it wasn't getting the expected JSON output (as it was being encoded differently)

Answer (score 0):

I received an illegal characters response from MailChimp using the code above until I switched to the md5_base64() call.